# How to set multi check box in jira using python

Tags: python, checkbox, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I actually want to enable First time Resolution check box via python which is displayed in the Resolved workflow in a separate window I could fetch the feild Id. I have tried many ways but couldn't succeed.(Python)

here are few ways I have tried:

1. `issue.fields.customfield_10112 = [{"value": "Resolved First Time"}]` or `[{"value": "Yes"}]`

The above hasn't worked.

2. `fields = {"customfield_10112": [{"value": "Resolved First Time"}]}`
   `issue.update(fields=fields)`

the above method I have tried  throws an error-text: *Field 'customfield_10112' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.*

I am attaching a screenshot of which checkbox should be enabled.

[image]

I would request anyone to help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Python code, you're editing the issue. But your screenshot comes from the *Resolved* transition.

When you edit an issue, only fields available on the 'Edit screen' can be updated (incl. REST API methods). The field *First Time Resolution* (`customfield_10112`) is most probably not on the Edit screen, i.e. the field can be changed only through the Resolved transition (the field is on the 'transition screen').

In other words, **you have to transition the issue** and pass the function the field(s) you want to change.

```
issue = jira.issue('MYISSUE-1')
fields = {
    "customfield_10112" : [{"value": "Resolved First Time"}],
    "resolution"        : { 'id': '3'}} # Resolution is mandatory on your screen
jira.transition_issue(issue, '5', fields=fields)
```

See this:
https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#transitions